# SVG hover fill doesn't work in FireFox

Tags: html, css, svg

I firstly add fill for SVG, then on :hover change it to another color. It works in all browsers except FireFox (don't know about IE).

```
svg {
  height: 25px;
  width: 40px;
  fill: #fff;
}
.facebook:hover {
  fill: #3b5998;
}
```

It works fine in FF when I delete first fill for svg, but that's obviously not a solution.

Any ideas how to fix that?

Here is a pen http://codepen.io/shatkovski/pen/aZzmJJ?editors=1100

Answer (score 1):

Firefox svg hover doesn't work well with <use>.

If you put the path inside the svg element, it works fine:

```
<svg class="facebook" viewBox="0 0 510 510">                                           
    <path d="M459 0H51C23 0 0 23 0 51v408c0 28.1 23 51 51 51h408c28.1 0 51-22.9 51-51V51C510 23 487.1 0 459 0zM433.5 51v76.5h-51c-15.3 0-25.5 10.2-25.5 25.5v51h76.5v76.5H357V459h-76.5V280.5h-51V204h51v-63.7C280.5 91.8 321.3 51 369.8 51H433.5z" />
</svg>
```

Comment: Isn't Firefox - according to the specs - behaving correctly here? The [SVG 1.1 specs](https://www.w3.org/TR/SVG/struct.html#UseElement) say: "CSS2 selectors cannot be applied to the (conceptually) cloned DOM tree because its contents are not part of the formal document structure." The statement "doesn't work well" is therefore somewhat misleading.

Comment: @ThomasW it applies style but doesn't want to redefine it. When "fill" is not applied for svg - hover works as expected

Comment: @ThomasW - what I meant is that it doesn't work well relative to other browsers that implement it in an intuitive way.